# Zend DB/Adapter/Query() how to run a wildcard search

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I'm amending this query to have wildcard search, but I can't seem to get it to run with the regular wildcards anywhere. What is the proper implementation

```
$customers = $this->adapter->query("SELECT c.* FROM `customers` c WHERE c.bundle_id=? AND c.last_sent_at IS NOT NULL AND c.email LIKE ? ORDER BY id DESC",[$id,$get])->toArray();
```

This should reflect a wildcard search like

```
WHERE c.email LIKE '% ? %'
```

but that doesn't seem to work. What is the proper syntax for wildcards in this context?

Thanks!

Comment: The first line of code is a non-wildcard search, the second line is just a demonstration of what I'm trying to accomplish in SQL. I got it working and posted my answer

Answer (score 1):

it works if I wrap the string with wildcards just make sure there are no quotes around it.

```
$get = "%$get%";
```